# Empty Window JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

My code compile, but i have empty windows. I think that FXML loading isnt good. Thanks for help!

```
 package application;


 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;

 public class Main extends Application {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)  {

    try{
    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/StackPaneWindow.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

StackPaneWindows.fxml has only button. I cant paste.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the fxml file:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/StackPaneWindow.fxml"));
Parent node = loader.load()
StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(node);
```

And you can put the `StackPane` as root node in your fxml file, then you can load the file like:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/StackPaneWindow.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load);
```

Comment: Bro! You're awesome!